# Is it possible to move a std::unique_ptr to itself?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a situation where I would like a `unique_ptr` that could be a class, or its decorator as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> b = std::make_unique<Derived>();

if (needsDecorator)
{
   b = std::make_unique<Decorator>(std::move(b));
}
```

where

```
class Derived: public Concrete {...}
class DecoratorC : public Base {...}
```

Is moving `b` to itself invalid?

Thank you!

Comment: You are not moving class you are moving objects. `MyClass` is class where `MyClass o` o is an object of class (type) `MyClass`, classes cannot be moved, while objects can.

Comment: Thanks, yes.  I changed the names. I'm trying to move the `unique_ptr` to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new unique pointer from an old one, not moving one into itself.

If this code ran:

```
pClass = std::make_unique<ClassDecorator>(std::move(pClass));
```

It would take the pClass, move it while constructing a ClassDecorator from it.  However, your ClassDecorator class would need to have a constructor that takes a unique_ptr for this to work.

Here's an example that may show what the decorated class needs:

```
#include <memory>

class Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base 
{
};

class Decorated : public Base {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr;

public:
    // THIS CONSTRUCTOR (or something like it) is what's missing
    Decorated(std::unique_ptr<Base> other) : ptr(std::move(other)) { }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> something = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    something = std::make_unique<Decorated>(std::move(something));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Hm, interesting. I didn't know.. so I wouldn't be able to correctly assign the derived class to the base class? I guess that's why I'm getting a linker error... `undefined reference to Decorator::Decorator(std::unique_ptr<Base>, std::default_delete<Base>)`

Comment: You can assign a derived pointer to base pointer, but not a base to derived.  But with objects (like you're allocating with make_unique), you can do whatever you want with its constructors signatures to decide what is allowable for its initialization.